# Missing leader in Vim

Tags: vim

It took me almost two years of programming till I decided to switch Textmate for Vim and I love it so far. However, after playing with it for a few days I hit a first issue.

As a beginner I reached for Janus as many people do but in the end I decided to create my own configuration from scratch to get to know the stuff better. I backed my configs up and started writing my new `.vimrc` file. But later on (pretty early) I noticed that leader key isn't working, it does nothing when I press it, well it just beeps. I didn't change the key for a leader nor did any key mapping so I was kinda surprised.

So once again I removed my `.vimrc` file and `.vim` directory to start with a clean state. It didn't help. So I opened Vim and tried to reconfigure a leader to a different key to see if it helps.

```
:let mapleader
> E121: Undefined variable: mapleader
:let mapleader = ','
:let mapleader
> mapleader          ,
```

Looks fine but nothing really happened. Even when I put it under a different key my Mac just beeps and thats it. There's no vim configuration in my home directory, no plugins, nothing. Setting leader in '.vimrc' instead of vim console doesn't help either.

I saw some discussions here on timeouts for key pressing but it have not got me anywhere.

I'm kinda stuck here and not able to use Vim for my day to day job even if I'd love to. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you have no vimrc, what maps are you using to test mapleader's functionality?

Comment: I just press leader key, I expect it to show in console below like it does when you type `:`. Check my comment under Conner's answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow these steps carefully…

1. Create a blank `.vimrc` file in your `$HOME` directory:

   ```
   $ cd
   $ touch .vimrc
   ```

   Vim should now run in "nocompatible" mode which is what we all want.
2. Open your blank `~/.vimrc` and add these lines:

   ```
   let mapleader=","
   nnoremap <leader>a :echo("\<leader\> works! It is set to <leader>")<CR>
   ```
3. Hit `,a`, you should obtain the following message in the command line.

   ```
   <leader> works! It is set to ,
   ```

`<leader>` may not be useful right from the start, though, there are other things to worry about.

Anyway, from there, I'd suggest you to add these few *non-opinionated* settings that will make your life considerably easier:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
set autoindent
set hidden
set incsearch
```

1. `filetype plugin indent on` allows Vim to recognize the filetype of the files you open and to apply all sorts of built-in filetype-specific settings (indent rules, completion…).
2. `syntax on` turns syntax highlighting on.
3. `set autoindent` copies the indent of the current line when you do `<CR>` life sucks so much if this is off.
4. `set hidden` allows you to open a new file or switch to another buffer without saving the changes to the current one.
5. `set incsearch` makes search-based navigation (`/foo`, `?bar`) instantly *awesome* by turning incremental search on.

After that, it's up to you to add settings and mappings as you need them.

Answer (score 6):

It's working, but the mappings preceding the change won't understand the changed leader character. For example, if I have a .vimrc that says

```
nnoremap <Leader>a :echo "test"<cr>
```

Then I can start up vim and hit `\a` to get `test` in the bottom left. However, if you type `:let mapleader = ','` then do `,a` it doesn't work because you changed leader after the mapping. If you then type `:nnoremap <Leader>a :echo "test"<cr>` and try `,a` again it will work. Thus, `:let mapleader =` must come before mappings that use `<Leader>`.

Comment: I understand that but thats the weird thing. I put `nnoremap <Leader>a :echo "test"<cr>` in `.vimrc` (only thing there), go to vim, press `\a`. It beeps for `\ ` and puts me into insert mode like `a` does. Same if I add `let mapleader=","` to `.vimrc` before the mapping and fire up Vim.

Comment: Both MacVim and Vim in terminal are 7.3

Comment: Do you have a .gvimrc, .vim/, or any other vim related file/folder? I'm also running 7.3 and not experiencing your results.

Comment: Thats exactly the thing thats bugging me a lot, I know you won't be able to reproduce. I removed all vim related stuff from my home directory. There's no `.vimrc`, `.gvimrc` or `.vim/` what so ever. It just happened, I removed my configs trying to put together my very own, put some basic stuff like size of tabs in, nothing really important and then noticed I can't use leader commands. So I removed all again (eventually many times) but it didn't help, I don't know what am I missing.

Comment: You could have modified runtime files. You might try reinstalling vim.

Comment: I already tried to reinstall MacVim. I don't know how exactly MacVim works, but I think it doesn't use system version of Vim, instead it has one embedded into itself (not sure). I'm experiencing this issue both with MacVim and the system Vim, that's bugging me. I googled a lot but I seem to be "lucky", I haven't found anyone with the same issue. And thats suspicious..

Comment: Do you have a ~/.viminfo file? If so try deleting it.

Comment: Since your problem is isolated and unlikely to aid future viewers of this question, you might seek some troubleshooting help in #vim on freenode of irc.

Comment: Deleting ~/.viminfo doesn't help either. Ok, I will try to seek for help on irc tomorrow. Thanks for your assistance and time. I highly appreciate it.